# How to filter terms which have multiple values to match exactly the specified values

Tags: elasticsearch

I am fairly new to elasticsearch, and need to update an existing system that is using the elasticsearch DSL.

The documents stored look something like this (simplified for this question):

```json
{
 "id" : "123",
 "tags" : [
  "name" : "STATES",
  "attrs" : [
    {
      "key" : "state",
      "value" : "NY"
    },
    {
      "key" : "state",
      "value" : "ND"
    }
  ]
 ]
}
```

```json
{
 "id" : "456",
 "tags" : [
  "name" : "STATES",
  "attrs" : [
    {
      "key" : "state",
      "value" : "ND"
    }
  ]
 ]
}
```

The number of key-value pairs can be of any size (including empty). Now I want to be able to filter those that have their state value match some states (for example 'ND' and 'NE') but NOT match any others. So the query should return the entry with id `456` but **not** `123`.

The best I came up with so far is the following, which is catching the ones with ND and NE, but it is still bringing up documents like the one with id `123`. I tried to use double negation but it doesn't seem to work.

```json
{
  "bool": {
    "must": [
      {
        "nested": {
          "path": "tags",
          "query": {
            "bool": {
              "filter": [
                {
                  "match": {
                    "tags.name": "STATES"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "nested": {
                    "path": "tags.attrs",
                    "query": {
                      "bool": {
                        "filter" : [
                          {
                            "bool": {
                              "must": [
                                {
                                  "match": {
                                    "tags.attrs.key": "state"
                                  }
                                },
                                {
                                  "terms": { "tags.attrs.value": [ "NE",  "ND" ] }
                                }
                              ]
                            }
                          },{
                            "bool" : {
                              "must_not" : [
                                {
                                  "bool" : {
                                    "must_not" : [
                                      {
                                        "match": {
                                          "tags.attrs.key": "state"
                                        }
                                      },
                                      {
                                        "terms": { "tags.attrs.value": [ "NE", "ND" ] }
                                      }
                                    ]
                                  }
                                }
                              ]
                            }
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Is there a simpler way to tell it to match those that have `tags.attrs.value` either "NE" or "ND" and but nothing else?

Thanks!